# Publishing Redshift table to Tableau server using python

Tags: python-3.x, tableau-api, tableau-desktop

I was wondering if there was a way to publish a Redshift table (select * from table essentially) to Tableau server site using Python?

I tried looking online but couldn't really find anything.

I want to have a process where a script detects if a new table has been added to Redshift database, and if so, publishes to Tableau server as a datasource.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to use Python for this

You can easily take an [extract](https://help.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/extracting_addfromfile.htm) of the full table and save it as a published data source in Tableau Server

However, there is a better alternative to Extract, its called Virtual connections

If you have Tableau Server 2022+, then you can utilize this feature: [Virtual Connections in Tableau](https://help.tableau.com/current/server/en-us/dm_vconn_create_conn.htm)